# Table tools on jquery datatable ? Minor issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Well i been working on exporting my datatable data . 
I tried the below link which mentioned some code but in my case i am getting nothing .
LINK : http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/

My code :

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnGuru").click(function () {
            tableToExcel('myDataTable', 'W3C Example Table');
        });

        $.datepicker.regional[""].dateFormat = 'dd/mm/yy';
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['']);
        debugger;
        var dt = $('#myDataTable').dataTable({

            "sDom": 'T<"H"plfr>t<"F"ip>',
            "oTableTools": {
                "aButtons": [ "csv", "pdf" ],
                "sSwfPath": "https://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
            },


            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "Home/AjaxHandler",
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "aoColumns": [
                                    {
                                        "sName": "Lead_Id",
                                        "bVisible": false,
                                        "bSearchable": false,
                                        "bSortable": false
                                    },
                       {
                           "sName": "Contact_Name"  ,
                           "bSearchable": false,
                           "bSortable": false,
                           "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                               return '<a href=\"Home/Details/' + oObj.aData[0] + '\">' + oObj.aData[1] + '</a>';
                           }
                       },
                       { "sName": "Contact_Address" },
                       { "sName": "Lead_Source" },
                       { "sName": "Domain" }
            ]

        });
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is highly recommended that you have the "sSwfPath" files in a local directory inside your project. I suggest you download them.  Also, I believe the "sDom" should be different too (check the link you have posted yourself).

My suggestion is that you initialize "sDom" along with the table and initialize Table Tools later on. Last but not least, add the local source to swf in the end.

```
var dt = $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
                "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "Home/AjaxHandler",
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "aoColumns": [
                                {
                                    "sName": "Lead_Id",
                                    "bVisible": false,
                                    "bSearchable": false,
                                    "bSortable": false
                                },
                   {
                       "sName": "Contact_Name"  ,
                       "bSearchable": false,
                       "bSortable": false,
                       "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                           return '<a href=\"Home/Details/' + oObj.aData[0] + '\">' + oObj.aData[1] + '</a>';
                       }
                   },
                   { "sName": "Contact_Address" },
                   { "sName": "Lead_Source" },
                   { "sName": "Domain" }
        ]

    });

TableTools.DEFAULTS.aButtons = [ "csv", "pdf" ];
TableTools.DEFAULTS.sSwfPath = your path here!
// this is the way I did it
//TableTools.DEFAULTS.sSwfPath = "<?php echo $this->basePath() ?>/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf";
```

Try this out.